# Convert Struct data type to Map data type in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, struct, type-conversion, user-defined-functions

How can I convert a column with the data type of struct to Map or String. This is the schema:

```
root
 |-- Col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)
```

The second column makes the problem when I want to dump the dataframe into a file. I have tried many different ways such as casting to string but it changed the values in the second column. I also tried to convert the Col2 to a map but i was not successful.

I tried to get the first value in struct(_1) through a udf but it has error:

Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (struct<_1:string,_2:int>) => string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select Col1, Col2._1, Col2._2 from <your table>
```

By spark.sql, you can try this and save it to another dataframe and then write to CSV.

Comment: Thanks!  This is the way I did it using your suggestion in Scala:  var df_new = df_old.select($"col1", $"col2._1", $"col2._2")

Answer (score 1):

In Scala we could do in this way:

```
val df_new = df_old.select($"Col1", $"Col2._1", $"Col3._2")
```

Comment: It is not a great practice to use vars in scala unless you are planning to make df_new mutable

Answer (score 1):

You can also * notation to expand all the columns from Struct data type.

Schema

```
root
|-- address: struct (nullable = false)
|    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
|    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```

Expansion SQL

```
val df1 = df.select("address.*").show(false)
df1.printSchema
root
 |-- street: string (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
```